# How to fix backwards incompatibility of mu 1.4?

Tags: mu4e

I upgraded `mu` from 1.2.0_1 to 1.4.1 and it does not seem backwards compatible. I immediately got a problem of `mu server process ended with exit code 127 error in process sentinel:`, which I solved from [this issue](https://github.com/djcb/mu/issues/1316) with:

```
mu init
mu find hello
mu index
```

I can now read emails and have two problems in the `mu4e` setup, even after restarting the system. When I compose an email, I get:

```
error in process filter: concat: Symbol’s value as variable is void: mu4e-compose-auto-include-date
error in process filter: Symbol’s value as variable is void: mu4e-compose-auto-include-date
```

and when delayed sending timer runs (`mu4e-send-delay`), I get:

```
Error running timer ‘mu4e-send-delay-send-queue’: (void-variable mu4e-maildir)
```

How can I fix these errors in the upgrade from 1.2.1 to 1.4?

Comment: Maybe remove `mu4e-compose-auto-include-date` from your configuration. There's a note on `mu4e-maildir` [here](https://github.com/djcb/mu/blob/0f5f6c4e13aa6fc607de5bcb30bf5f62db9e9188/NEWS.org).

Comment: The developer(s) of the Lisp version of `mu4e` refuse to permit a Lisp version to be different than the executable version -- this is done purposefully to reduce bug reports to the Lisp version maintainer(s).  Therefore, ensure your Lisp version matches *exactly* with the the executable version.  See https://github.com/djcb/mu/issues/1298

Comment: @lawlist I checked the link. I believe my versions are in sync: `mu --version` shows `mu (mail indexer/searcher) version 1.4.1`, and the Emacs variable `mu4e-mu-version` is `mu4e-mu-version is a variable defined in ‘mu4e-meta.el’.
Its value is "1.4.1"`.

Comment: @jagrg I did a `grep` search for `mu4e-compose-auto-include-date` in my configuration directory and got no matches. I checked the link: `mu init` was already showing my maildir at `~/Maildir`. I ran `mu init --my-address` to fill that one. The error upon composing an email remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is more with `mu4e-send-delay` than with `mu4e` itself. Can you confirm which version of `mu4e-send-delay` you are using? [That one](https://github.com/bandresen/mu4e-send-delay)? I'm asking because I found out several different versions, but the canonical seems to be the one I linked.

This plugin seems abandoned by its creator (no update since 3 years). But maybe he will answer if you open an issue there.

In the meantime, another solution, instead of changing yourself the code of `mu4e-send-delay`, may be to artificially recreate the [missing variable](https://github.com/djcb/mu/blob/1.4.3/mu4e/mu4e-draft.el#L68) in your Emacs config file:

```lisp
(defvar mu4e-compose-auto-include-date t
  "Recreate an old mu4e var needed by `mu4e-send-delay'.")
```

For the other error regarding `mu4e-maildir`, it's exactly the same: [this is an old variable](https://github.com/djcb/mu/blob/1.4.3/mu4e/mu4e-vars.el#L54) removed from `mu4e`, but still (as there'd been no update) present in `mu4e-send-delay`. Thus same cure for it:

```lisp
(defvar mu4e-maildir "Path to your maildir"
  "Recreate an old mu4e var needed by `mu4e-send-delay'.")
```

However, I think it's a bad idea to use this plugin as it is no more compatible with mu4e. It may need a major refactoring to work with last version of mu4e. Thus either you should consider leaving it, or downgrading mu/mu4e if you absolutely need it.

Comment: Yes, the problem was in `mu4e-send-delay`, I have removed it, and it all works now. I was using version `20170610.0636`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is perhaps in the definition of `mu4e-send-delay-setup`.

You have to comment the following line

```
   ...
   (when mu4e-compose-auto-include-date
   ...
```

and also delete a ")" at the end of definition of the function.

You should obtain

```
...
(mu4e~draft-header mu4e-send-delay-header mu4e-send-delay-default-delay))))
```

Restart Emacs and it should be ok.